# How is user input handled in MVC vs MVP?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, mvp

I've been reading up on MVC vs MVP and a point that is often made is that MVC differs from MVP in how it handles it's user input.

In MVP the view delegates the user input to the Presenter and in MVC the Controller is supposedly the only part of the application that manages the user input.

This seems a bit odd to me. I have never came across a GUI framework, where i didn't have to delegate events raised in the view (mostly some sort of widget) to somewhere else, to perform some action based on the event raised.

If that's the case, is there even a difference between MVC and Supervising Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. MVC and MVP are completely different, however they're both a pattern for seperation of concerns in the UI.

In MVC, controller handles the requests (through routing) and pushes data into the views, whereas in MVP all events and rendering is being handled in views and presenter just handles the business logic of UI. This makes the UI testable. There is no url routing in MVP.

MVP is suitable for windows apps and ASP.net Webforms, and MVC is more compatible with Web applications (Java spring MVC, or Asp.net MVC,etc) .

Comment: I should have added that i was only talking about non-web applications. Maybe it's a good thing that MVP is getting a popular term for desktop application structural patterns, since MVC is associated with web development way too much nowadays.

Comment: Exactly, and in terms of desktop apps it depends on the type of technology you are using. If it's something like Windows Form Apps, MVP is the best fit whereas for techs like WPF and silverlight, MVVM is more suitable. Generally speaking, if you've got binding feature in your UI tech MVVM is a better choice.

Comment: In the end MVP and all it's variations (I would call MVVM a MVP variation) do the same thing with different mechanics. I just came across the definition in my question on some site that compared MVP with the MVC pattern that got popular through the smalltalk community and got a bit confused.